# Django reverse (on_delete) protection on a model instance

Tags: django, django-models, django-model-field

Is is possible to protect a model in a reverse relationship. For instance in the models below:-

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_field1 = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True)

class Bar(models.Model):
    bar_field1 = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True)
    bar_field2 = models.CharField(max_length=56, unique=True)
```

If an attempt is made to delete an instance of `Foo`, it wont be deleted as the `on_delete` attribute on `Bar` is set to `models.PROTECT`. So, is it possible to extend that protection both ways? That is, if an attempt is made to delete an instance of `Bar`, so can it be protected just like `Foo`, can someone suggest a solution?.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a full solution for you, but I would suggest looking into using a [Django Signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/signals/#pre-delete), specifilly `pre-delete`. You would in that signal check if `bar_field_1` in instance of `Bar` is null and abort the deletion if it is not null.

Comment: Yes, I guess you may be right, and I suppose django doesn't provides a built-in functionality to do this. May be because this would essentially block deletion on both tables. Anyway can you please guide me on how can I abort the instance deletion in ```pre-delete```?